# Calculating speed to interval reverse ratio

Tags: c++, arduino

This might be a slightly unusual question and I have a feeling this is a simple task and yet I struggle to find a solution.

I have an arduino project for controlling an valve based on rotational speed of a wheel. The valve needs to be opened in specific time intervals. I have a predefined maximum interval variable as well as minimum interval (both in seconds). I also have a minimum speed (in km/h), below which the valve will stay closed.

So let's assume:

```
min_v = 20;
max_interval = 60;
min_interval = 1;
```

All of the above values might possibly be change based on requirements.

How do I calculate the current opening interval based on current speed? Important thing to note is that the interval has to decrease as the speed increases.

Not sure if I also need to assume a max speed for this to be possible?

Comment: Time = Distance / Speed. If you know the speed of the wheel you can work out the time. However, you will need to know the distance it travels. What is not clear from your question is how the wheel controls the valve and I think this is important (if not vital) to understand how to answer your question.

Comment: As I mentioned, the increase of speed should decrease the interval between valve openings

Comment: How, about assuming that `min_interval` occurs when speed is infinity. And, we know `max_interval` occurs at 'min_v`. Now, make a function relating speed to interval that fullfills these conditions. Like a simple function will be - `curr_speed = c / (curr_interval - min_interval)` where `c` is constant and can be found using our other condition. Now, rearrange terms to get `curr_interval` in terms of `curr_speed`. And if `curr_speed` is  less than `min_v`, `curr_interval` is `infinity`.

Comment: The standard formula I quoted will have the result that, as the speed increases, the time interval will decrease. Do you have a speed and Time pair of values eg at speed X, I want the time interval to be Y? If so, what are those values?

Comment: Let's assume the following speed to interval relation for now:

20 - 60;

220 - 1;

Comment: you can make something like `v = (x - min_interval) / (max_int - min int)  * (v_max-v_min) + v_min` and rearrange. Btw `v` is current speed and `x` iscurrent interval. @RobAnthony tagging you just so you get notification and suggest any improvements, if possible ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure my rearrangement is correct. I did something like this: `min_interval + ( (max_interval - min_interval) / (max_speed - min_speed) )* v`
But I'm getting the opposite result than desired - the interval increases with speed

Comment: Also the result jumps between positive and negative values as the speed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's my formula that seems to be working:

```
currentInterval = maxOpeningInterval - ((maxOpeningInterval - minOpeningInterval) / (maxSpeed - minSpeed) * currentSpeed);
```